# Checking every key of map in java as null check

Tags: java

I have the below code in which I am iterating over a map and then setting the result of each key into an entity but this is I am doing for each key which looks a bit odd as shown below, I am using java 11 jdk please tell me how can I shorten this piece of code so that lots of IF conditions can be avoided

```
@Override
    public AfdLoginDTO toEnt(Map<String, Object> map) {
        AfdLoginDTO afdLogin = new AfdLoginDTO();
        if (map.get("username") != null) {
            afdLogin.setUsername(map.get("username").toString());
        }
        if (map.get("nt_id") != null) {
            afdLogin.setClientId(map.get("nt_id").toString());
        }

        return afdLogin;
    }
```

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better fit for this sort of question, as you're looking to improve code that works

Answer (score 4):

With a helper method and using lambdas, the code can be simplified as follows:

```
static void setIfPresent(Map<String, Object> map, String key, Consumer<Object> setter) {
    Object value = map.get(key);
    if (value != null) {
        setter.accept(value);
    }
}
```

```
AfdLoginDTO toEnt(Map<String, Object> map) {
    AfdLoginDTO afdLogin = new AfdLoginDTO();
    setIfPresent(map, "username"   , o -> afdLogin.setUsername(o.toString()));
    setIfPresent(map, "nt_id"      , o -> afdLogin.setClientId(o.toString()));
    setIfPresent(map, "abc_id"     , o -> afdLogin.setUserId(o.toString()));
    setIfPresent(map, "nhck_status", o -> afdLogin.setLockstatus(o.toString()));
    setIfPresent(map, "abc_time"   , o -> afdLogin.setLocktime(Date.from((Instant) o)));
    return afdLogin;
}
```

---

If you prefer method references over lambdas, then an alternate helper method might do:

```
static <E> void setIfPresent(Map<String, Object> map, String key, Consumer<E> setter, Function<Object, E> mapper) {
    Object value = map.get(key);
    if (value != null) {
        setter.accept(mapper.apply(value));
    }
}
```

```
AfdLoginDTO toEnt(Map<String, Object> map) {
    AfdLoginDTO afdLogin = new AfdLoginDTO();
    setIfPresent(map, "username"   , afdLogin::setUsername  , Object::toString);
    setIfPresent(map, "nt_id"      , afdLogin::setClientId  , Object::toString);
    setIfPresent(map, "abc_id"     , afdLogin::setUserId    , Object::toString);
    setIfPresent(map, "nhck_status", afdLogin::setLockstatus, Object::toString);
    setIfPresent(map, "abc_time"   , afdLogin::setLocktime  , o -> Date.from((Instant) o));
    return afdLogin;
}
```

---

Both of the above solutions use the same terminology as e.g. [`Map.computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-):

> If the value for the specified key is *present and non-null*, ...

If you however want a key that is present but null to mean that you want the setter method to be called with a null value, while a key that is absent to mean to not call the method, the second solution can be modified to do that:

```
static <E> void setIfPresent(Map<String, Object> map, String key, Consumer<E> setter, Function<Object, E> mapper) {
    Object value = map.get(key);
    if (value != null) {
        setter.accept(mapper.apply(value));
    } else if (map.containsKey(key)) {
        setter.accept(null);
    }
}
```

The mapper will still only be called for non-null values, so this will not cause NullPointerExceptions.

Answer (score -1):

Try using ternary operator as below

```
afdLogin.setUsername(map.get("username")!=null?map.get("username").toString(),null);
```

Comment: That doesn't compile. --- Also, result deviates from original code, since the setter method is always called, while original code doesn't call the setter method if map doesn't have a value.